# Django forms.DateInput does not apply the attributes given in attrs field

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-1.4

Placeholder, class not getting set when tried to apply through the django's attrs specifier for [forms.DateInput](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#dateinput)

The form is a [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/).

And according to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#dateinput)

> Takes same arguments as TextInput, with one more optional argument:

Here is the code :

```
widgets = {
   'my_date_field': forms.DateInput(format=('%d-%m-%Y'), 
                    attrs={'class':'myDateClass', 
                           'placeholder':'Select a date'}
                    )
}
```

The same is applied for a `forms.TextInput` and it works just fine.

What am I missing here?

Just anybody wants a full class code :

```
class trademark_form(ModelForm):
    my_date_field = DateField(input_formats=['%d-%m-%Y'])
    class Meta:
        model = myModel

        widgets = {
                   'my_date_field': forms.DateInput(format=('%d-%m-%Y'), attrs={'class':'myDateClass', 'placeholder':'Select a date'}),
                   'field1': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'textInputClass', 'placeholder':'Enter a Value..'}),
                   'field2': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'textInputClass', 'placeholder':'Enter a Value..', 'readonly':'readonly', 'value':10}),
                   'desc': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'textAreaInputClass', 'placeholder':'Enter desc', 'rows':5}),

               }
        exclude = ('my_valid_field')
```

The generated HTML for the field, `my_date_field` :

```
<input type="text" id="id_my_date_field" name="my_date_field">
```

The generated HTML for the field, `field1` :

```
<input type="text" name="field1" class="textInputClass" placeholder="Enter a Value.." id="id_field1">
```

Comment: Can you show what render results in on your side. I am getting, <input type="text" placeholder="Select a date" class="myDateClass" value="7/11/2013" name="time" /> . Also what is the placeholder supposed to do here . Shouldn't you be using label

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since you <del>didn't post your form code, my best guess is that you explicitly instantiated a form field like this</del> confirmed my guess by posting the code that looks roughly like this:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    my_date_field = forms.DateField()

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        widgets = {
            'my_date_field': forms.DateInput(format=('%d-%m-%Y'), 
                                             attrs={'class':'myDateClass', 
                                            'placeholder':'Select a date'})
        }
```

I can say that it's not working because if you explicitly instantiate a form field like this, Django assumes that you want to completely define form field behavior; therefore, you can't use the `widgets` attribute of the inner `Meta` class.

The note at the end of section about [overriding the default field types or widgets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields) states that:

> Fields defined declaratively are left as-is, therefore any
>   customizations made to Meta attributes such as widgets, labels,
>   help_texts, or error_messages are ignored; these only apply to fields
>   that are generated automatically.

Comment: Check the updated in the question. And the answer you posted is irrelevant!

Comment: Thanks for the input. I still don't see this explicitly mentioned in the docs. Hence, my confusion. You are right.

Comment: I agree, it's not really clear. There are hints in the headline `'field types OR widgets'` and in the first paragraph of the note box.

Answer (score 3):

based on response of @Martin and reading the Django documentation the final solution should be:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    my_date_field = forms.DateField(
        widget=forms.DateInput(format=('%d-%m-%Y'), 
                               attrs={'class':'myDateClass', 
                               'placeholder':'Select a date'}))

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        widgets = {
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(format=('%d-%m-%Y'),attrs={'class': 'datepicker', 'placeholder': 'Select a date', 'type': 'date'}))
```

*when input type does not change this worked for me.*

Answer (score 1):

you can simply create a  HTML Datepicker Without using a fancy JAvascript Library.Here is the simple demo:

First create a dateinput field inherited from Dateinput:

```
 class DateInput(forms.DateInput):
     input_type = 'date'
```

And use this DateInput Field as like this :

```
 class BookingRoomForm(ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         widgets = {'checkin':DateInput()}
         model = BookingRoom
         fields = ['checkin',]
```

If you're not using ModelForm,Use widget something like this :

```
class BookingRoomForm(ModelForm):
    checkin = forms.DateField(widget=DateInput())
    class Meta:
        model = BookingRoom
        fields = ['checkin',]
```

And the output will be like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zvK6.png)

Answer (score 0):

i did different,

into the forms I apply this to my ModelForm

```
class Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MODEL
        fields = ['day']
        widget = {
            'day': DateInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Nome do tratamento',
                                         'id': 'id_day'})
        }
```

at my main tamplete I applied:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
Form here

<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#id_day" ).datepicker();
});
</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(format=('%d-%m-%Y'),attrs={'class': 'datepicker', 'placeholder': 'Select a date', 'type': 'date'}))
```

This worked in my case

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).